# Is there a way to append io.multiwriter with timestamp in go?

Tags: go, io, timestamp, logrus

I am dealing with logs generated in go. Things are printed to stdout and a log file using io.multiwriter`log := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logfile)`. I would like to add timestamps to both os.Stdout and logfile.

My approach is to write a write function

```
type writer struct {
    io.Writer
    timeFormat string
}

func (w writer) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return w.Writer.Write(append([]byte(time.Now().Format(w.timeFormat)), b...))
}
log := io.MultiWriter(&writer{os.Stdout, "2006/01/02 15:04:05"}, logFile)
```

However, it does not produce the timestamp both in Stdout and logfile. Does anyone know if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the timestamp doesn't show up in the log file is because only your writer adds the timestamp, not [`io.MultiWriter()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter).

Change your use to set the multi-writer to `writer.Writer`, so the timestamp will be sent to both writers: `os.Stdout` and `logFile`.

```
logFile := &bytes.Buffer{}
log := &writer{io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logFile), "2006/01/02 15:04:05"}
log.Write([]byte(" hi"))

fmt.Println("\nlogFile:", logFile)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Eln5OO91aMm)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 hi
logFile: 2009/11/10 23:00:00 hi
```

Also note that the [`log`](https://pkg.go.dev/log) package (combined with `io.MultiWriter`) gives you this functionality out of the box, you can set the output writer using [`log.SetOutput()`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#SetOutput):

```
logFile := &bytes.Buffer{}
log.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logFile))
log.Print("hi")

fmt.Println("logFile:", logFile)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IgQWUK_CQ__V)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 hi
logFile: 2009/11/10 23:00:00 hi
```

Moreover, the `log` package also provides formatting capabilities and configurable output.

Comment: Hi icza, after I tested the first approach in your answer, it works on its own. However, when I'm using exec.Cmd{stdout: log, stderr: log}, the answer fails it unlike log := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, plogFile). Do you have any idea why this would happen? Thank you very much!

Comment: You'd better post it as a new question, with [mcve], and describe the error (what "fails" mean).